# I want to delete the li tag when i click on the fontawesome icon for React ToDoList

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass } from 'react-dom/test-utils';

class MyToDo extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { items: [], text: '' };
  this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleInput(e) {
  this.setState({ text: e.target.value });
}

handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const old = {
    text: this.state.text,
    id: Date.now(),
  };
  if (this.state.text === '') {
    return;
  }

  this.setState({ items: this.state.items.concat(old), text: '' });
}






render() {

  return (
    <div className="text-center mt-5">
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <input
            placeholder="Enter todo"
            className="p-3"
            onChange={this.handleInput}
          />
        </div>

        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary mt-3">
          ADD
        </button>
      </form>
      <Index items={this.state.items} />
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default MyToDo;

class Index extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  
  
}

handleDelete(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  this.setState({ text: e.target.value });

}

render() {


  return (
    <div>
      {this.props.items.map((e) => (
        <div
          className="table-responsive mt-1 d-flex justify-content-center"
          key={e.id}
        >
          <table className="table table-dark w-50 text-center mb-0">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">
                  {e.text}
                  <i
                  onClick={this.handleDelete}
                    className="fas fa-window-close fa-2x float-end bg-danger"
                  ></i>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyToDo />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

This is my code. When I write sth inside the input then click on the add, i add new li tag to underneath.But my problem is to delete this li tags. I added to fontawesome icon a **handleDelete** **onclick** event. But i could not solve how to delete this. I added bind, and handleDelete function on parent component but it does not work. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `onClick={this.handleDelete}` try `() => this.props.handleDelete(e.id)`,
u should pass the handleDelete function to Index component props and add handleDelete to your parent component

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass } from 'react-dom/test-utils';

class MyToDo extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { items: [], text: '' };
  this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this):
}

handleInput(e) {
  this.setState({ text: e.target.value });
}
handleDelete(id) {
  const items = this.state.items.filter(item => item.id !== id);
  this.setState({ items });
}

handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const old = {
    text: this.state.text,
    id: Date.now(),
  };
  if (this.state.text === '') {
    return;
  }

  this.setState({ items: this.state.items.concat(old), text: '' });
}






render() {

  return (
    <div className="text-center mt-5">
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <input
            placeholder="Enter todo"
            className="p-3"
            onChange={this.handleInput}
          />
        </div>

        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary mt-3">
          ADD
        </button>
      </form>
      <Index items={this.state.items} handleDelete={handleDelete}/>
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default MyToDo;

class Index extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  
  
}

render() {


  return (
    <div>
      {this.props.items.map((e) => (
        <div
          className="table-responsive mt-1 d-flex justify-content-center"
          key={e.id}
        >
          <table className="table table-dark w-50 text-center mb-0">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">
                  {e.text}
                  <i
                  onClick={() => this.props.handleDelete(e.id)}
                    className="fas fa-window-close fa-2x float-end bg-danger"
                  ></i>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyToDo />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked.```() => this.props.handleDelete(e.id)``` Why did you use e.id  inside it?